# Bound for the laplacian of a strictly convex function from above by the gradient of it

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, convex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $V \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d; \mathbb{R})$ a (strictly) convex function with $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx = 1.$

I am trying to show that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x V(x) |^2\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx < +\infty.$$
My ideas:
(Due to strict convexity and $V$ is not constant and smooth on $\mathbb{R}^d$ we should have $ \lim_{|x| \to \infty} V(x) = + \infty.$ Perhabs this could be useful...)
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x V(x) |^2\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \nabla_x V(x) \cdot \nabla_x\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Delta_x V(x) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx.$$
(In the first step I used chain rule and just in the second step integration by parts.)
If I could estimate $\Delta_x V(x)$ in a certain way like:
$$ \Delta_x V(x) \leq \alpha + \beta |\nabla_x V(x) |^2$$ with $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta \in [0;1) $ it would work. Does this hold for all (strictly) convex functions with $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx = 1$? The inequality does not hold for all strictly convex functions like for $-\mathrm{ln}(x)$ on $(0, +\infty).$ So I suppose we will need an additional condition.

Or are there any other ideas?

Comment: Does the following heuristics work? for "reasonable" increasing functions of one real variable $v(z)$ the derivative $v'$ grows slower at infinity than the function itself. And "nice convex" functions behave roughly speaking as such nice one-dimensional functions (along radial directions). So essentially, one expects $|\nabla V|^2e^{-V}$ to be controlled by $o(|V|^2)e^{-V}$. The hard part becomes then how to quantify the $o$ term.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon: This follows from the second property here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables

Comment: I suppose you mean:
$$ V(x) \geq V(y) + \nabla V(y)^{\top} \cdot (x-y)$$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d. $
Actually I do not see how to use this in that case.